# Why doesn't this async code continue on the same context as before it was awaited?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await, configureawait

I'm working on trying to understand how [Task.ContinueWith](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.continuewith?view=netframework-4.7.2) works.  Consider the following code:

```
private async void HandleButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"HandleButtonClick: a {GetTrdLabel()}");
    var t1 = Task.Run(() => DoSomethingAsync("First time"));
    Console.WriteLine($"HandleButtonClick: b {GetTrdLabel()}");
    await t1;
    Console.WriteLine($"HandleButtonClick: c {GetTrdLabel()}");

    var t2 = t1.ContinueWith(async (t) =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"t3: a {GetTrdLabel()}");
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        Console.WriteLine($"t3: b {GetTrdLabel()}");
        await DoSomethingAsync("Second time");
        Console.WriteLine($"t3: c {GetTrdLabel()}");
    });

    Console.WriteLine($"HandleButtonClick: d {GetTrdLabel()}");
    await t2;
    Console.WriteLine($"HandleButtonClick: e {GetTrdLabel()}");
}

private async Task DoSomethingAsync(string label)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"DoSomethingElseAsync ({label}): a {GetTrdLabel()}");
    Thread.Sleep(2000);
    Console.WriteLine($"DoSomethingElseAsync ({label}): b {GetTrdLabel()}");
    await Task.Delay(2000);
    Console.WriteLine($"DoSomethingElseAsync ({label}): c {GetTrdLabel()}");
}

private string GetTrdLabel() => $"({Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId})";
```

The output is below.  My question is about the highlighted lines: why isn't the first one continuing on the captured context after the `await` -- i.e. managed thread ID `3` -- since I didn't use [`.ConfigureAwait(false)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.configureawait?view=netframework-4.7.2)?  The second one *is* continuing as expected -- i.e. thread ID `4`.

I feel like it has something to do with the "...**attempt** to marshal the continuation back to the original context captured" (emphasis mine) from the documentation, but I don't understand why the *attempt* fails in the first case.

[image]

Comment: You are confusing the thread Id with the context. `await` resumes in the same context, but all background threads share the same context. The first DoSomethingAsync runs on a background thread, so the `await` will resume on another background thread (which may be a different background thread from the one the task started on).

Answer (score 3):

> trying to understand how Task.ContinueWith works

It's better to just ignore `ContinueWith` and use `await` instead. But, if you would like to learn the [low-level, dangerous](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/10/continuewith-is-dangerous-too.html) way to do things, then I'll oblige. Please do not use in production.

The first thing to note is that `ContinueWith` always schedules work to a task scheduler. And it does *not* use the default task scheduler by default; it uses the *current* task scheduler by default. Assuming that `HandleButtonClick` is invoked directly by your UI framework (and not, e.g., scheduled using a task scheduler), then there is no current task scheduler, so `ContinueWith` will use the default task scheduler, which is the thread pool task scheduler. To avoid this kind of convoluted reasoning, code should *always* pass a `TaskScheduler` to `ContinueWith`.

The next thing to note is that `ContinueWith` does not understand `async` delegates. As far as it's concerned, an `async` lambda is just a fancy way to give it a `Func<Task>` delegate, and `ContinueWith` only cares about the initial synchronous part of that method.

The final thing to note is that thread pool threads are considered interchangeable. This is true for any `async`/`await` code; if it is running in a thread pool context and performs an `await`, it can resume executing on any thread pool thread. It may or may not be the same thread that was running the code before the `await`.